# Sidekiq Web Fails undefined method `failure_app' for nil:NilClass

Tags: devise, sidekiq

I have Sidekiq installed as follows:

```
  require 'sidekiq/web'
  Sidekiq::Web.set :sessions, false

  authenticate :admin do
    mount Sidekiq::Web => '/admin/sidekiq'
  end
```

Now Sidekiq web fails when I try to access it - this is local and in production.

```
NoMethodError at /unauthenticated
undefined method `failure_app' for nil:NilClass
```

> failure_appdevise (4.7.1) lib/devise/delegator.rb

```
def failure_app(env)
  app = env["warden.options"] &&
    (scope = env["warden.options"][:scope]) &&
    Devise.mappings[scope.to_sym].failure_app
  app || Devise::FailureApp
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stumbled on this:

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/2963#issuecomment-219590441

```
  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config

  authenticate :admin_user do
    mount Sidekiq::Web => '/admin/sidekiq'
  end
```

I had two mistakes in my code:

1. I was trying to authenticate Sidekiq via `:admin` and NOT `:admin_user`
2. Note the SINGULAR `:admin_user` - I still had the plural once I finally figure #1 out ‍♂️

Comment: Thanks - glad to help.  This one drove me crazy for a while.